# ASP.NET DynamicData - Insert Records from Datatable

Tags: asp.net-dynamic-data

In DynamicData,
I have a datatable generated at runtime dynamically for a table while user is viewing a page. I need to insert these records from datatable to database Table(based on dynamicdata table page).

How can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the INSERT.aspx template provided in Dynamic Data under the folders
Dynamic Data --> PageTemplates